# Not getting current state in onClick function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

New to react and redux and struggling with state management a bit. In the following code, I have a button. Clicking it triggers a two step function:

1) Call a reducer to do some validation and update a flag in state based on whether it succeeded or not.

2) Use the updated flag in state to notify a user if the validation failed, or proceed with the normal process if it succeeded.

```
transfer() {
  this.props.validateData();
  this.notifyOrSend(this.props.validationSucceeded);
}

notifyOrSend(validationSucceeded) {
  if (validationSucceeded === false) {
    this.refs.validationModal.showModal();
  } else {
    this.props.sendTransfer();
  }
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button label="Transfer" onClickFn={this.transfer}/>
        <ValidationModal ref="validationModal"/>
      </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    validationSucceeded: state.validatedData.validationSucceeded,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    validateData,
  }, dispatch);
}
```

My issue is that I am getting an old version of the flag (this.props.validationSucceeded). The flag's initial state is true. If it fails validation on the first click of the button, the value of this.props.validationSucceeded remains true. The change to false is only picked up on the second click. I can see in the console that the action that gets triggered has the latest value of the flag in nextState. How can I change this code to get that latest value?

Answer (score 1):

setState is more like an event, it doesn't happen right away hence why you can pass a second function to setState that will execute once it actually happens.

Since you are calling `notifyOrSend` immediately after, state will still be the same until the next render occurs. I would look into moving the `notifyOrSend` function into the appropriate lifecycle method for the component. I would assume it would either be `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillUpdate` depending on what the `notifyOrSend` function actually does.

from the react docs:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try componentWillUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps and they work on the initial click, but then there's a secondary issue. If the user doesn't correct the errant data, and the validation flag stays false, then the state doesn't change, and the lifecycle methods aren't called. I need the notification to trigger every time they click the button while the validation flag is false.

Comment: are you using shouldcomponentupdate anywhere? since state wont actually change it is more then likely not triggering a rerender of the component and never hits that logic. 

If it were me and I needed what you are asking i wouldn't do any of this through state and have `validateData` just be a function that returns true or false and not have it be tied to a reducer. Then you would just call notifyOrSend with the results of `validateData` but I can only see so much of your code and may not work for you